# How to execute solidity payable functions using hardhat js

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat

This is my solidity function:

```
function bid(uint256 bidAmount) public payable {
        require(vault.tokenExists(address(nftAddress), nftId, owner) == true, "There are no units of this token available for sale!");
        require(msg.value == bidAmount, "Bid amount must be equal to sent value");
        require(block.timestamp < endTime, "Auction has already ended");
        require(bidAmount > winningBid, "Bid amount must be greater than the winning bid");

        //Refund the previous winner's bid
        if (winner != address(0)) {
            winner.transfer(winningBid);
            emit BidRefunded(winner, winningBid);
        }

        // Add the new bid to the mapping and update the winning bid
        bids[msg.sender].push(Bid({bidder: payable(msg.sender), bidAmount: bidAmount}));
        winningBid = bidAmount;
        winner = payable(msg.sender);
        emit NewBid(msg.sender, bidAmount);
    }
```

I am trying to execute it using hardhat js:

```
  const Auction = await AuctionContract.attach('0xA6558F9fEDD69F55B056b5233a1cFcad9d45d242');
  const user_signer = new ethers.Wallet(account_one_privateKey, provider);
  const tokenPrice1 = ethers.utils.parseEther('0.0000000000000002');
  const sendValue = {
  value: tokenPrice1,
  };
  const Bid = await Auction.connect(user_signer).bid(200000,sendValue);
  console.log(Bid);
  console.log(Bid.hash);
```

its throwing me this error:

```
    reason: 'processing response error',
        code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
        body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":49,"error":
{"code":-32000,"message":"insufficient funds for transfer"}}\n',
```

Comment: the `account_one_privateKey` doesn't have money, that's why it gives you this error

Answer (score 0):

Which provider are you using?
As I guess you're wanna run the script on a specified network, you should:

1. Define network inside hardhat.config, like:

```
networks: {
    polygonMumbai: {
      url: "https://matic-mumbai.chainstacklabs.com",
      chainId: 80001,
      accounts: ["your_private_key"]
    }
}
```

2. Run your script with the command:

```
npx hardhat run path_to_script --network polygonMumbai
```